# Prove column space of a matrix spans $\mathbb R^m$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that the column space of a square matrix $A$ of size $m\times m$ spans $\mathbb R^m$ if and only if the matrix equation $Ax=b$ has a solution for each $b$ in $\mathbb R^m$.

I know the fact that $Ax=b$ has a solution if and only if $b$ is a linear combination of column vectors of $A$, but how do I interpret this fact such that I obtain the conclusion that the column space of $A$ is a basis for $\mathbb R^m$? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $Ax = b$ has a solution for each $b \in \mathbb R^m$ $\implies$ $b$ is a linear combination of column vectors of $A$, i.e. 
$$b = c_1A_1 + \ldots +c_nA_m,$$ 
where $A_1,\dots,A_m$ are the column vectors of $A$. Well this tells you that any vector in $\mathbb R^m$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the columns of $A$, which is precisely what it means for the column space of $A$ to span $\mathbb R^m.$ So you have the "$\implies$" direction. The other direction shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If we have $A = [A_1, \dots, A_m]$, where $A_i$ denote the columns of $A$ then for a vector $x = (x_1, \dots, x_m)^T$ we get 
$$
Ax = \sum_{i=1}^m x_i A_i
$$
is a linear combination of the columns of $A$. This means that $\{ Ax \mid x \in \mathbb{R}^m \} = \mathrm{span}(A_1, \dots, A_m)$, which is precisely what you were looking for.

Comment: What you've shown is that the image of the mapping $x \mapsto Ax$ equals the span of the columns of $A$, but it doesn't answer the question directly (granted it is only 1 or 2 lines away)

Comment: @peek-a-boo OP was asking to prove the statement $\mathrm{im}(A) = \mathbb{R}^m \iff \mathrm{span}(A_1, \dots, A_m) = \mathbb{R}^m$, which readily follows from the equality $\mathrm{im}(A) = \mathrm{span}(A_1, \dots, A_m)$. But I suppose you were right and I could have made it more explicit.